# Music Effects Option in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

upto android `kitkat API`  whenver user installs new `music equalizer` application then user can change default music equalizer from 
`Settings -> sounds -> music effects` then he can choose default equalizer applicaiton for music player.
But in lollipop after installing the application also it is not showing music effects in settings.

then how to change the music equalizer application for native player in Lollipop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing lot of R & D , i got solution that by default in lollipop there is no Music Effects option in lollipop. if you want to gain that feature you have to disable the default music equalizer. by following following steps

`Settings -> Application Manager -> All -> Music Fx -> Disable`.  after disabling the default music equalizer. when the user opens from the music player application. at that time it will show one intent chooser. in that one our application will be there.

for that activity we have to keep `AudioEffect.ACTION_OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION` action in manifest then only our application will be shown in that chooser.

Comment: cant found Settings -> Application Manager -> All -> Music Fx -> Disable